# Show only Progressbar while load listview on Android

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

I'm using listview on Android to show some information from internet with a custom adapter using searcheable activity. I'm using a indeterminate custom progress bar to show while my App is looking for criteria search.

I trying to show first the progress bar and then the listview fill with data.

This is my code but the progress bar is show on listview after the first search....

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_layout, container,false);

    //Progress bar
    progressBarSearch = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBarSearch);

    //Hide progress bar
    progressBarSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return rootView;
}


public class SearchFromGoogle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<SearchItems>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        //Show progress bar
        progressBarSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<VideoYoutube> doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        //My code
    }

    @Override        
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SearchItems> resultList) {

        adapterSearch = new SearchListAdapter(getActivity(), resultList, getListView());        
        setListAdapter(adapterSearch);

        //Hide progress bar
        progressBarSearch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```